# Rotating rectangles on an arc in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to position rectangles on d3js arcs at 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees. Here is a simple example I put together that uses an arc generator to create 4 arcs and the arc.centroid function to place the rectangles at the center points of each arc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>Rotate rectangles to arc positions: 0, 90, 180 & 270 </title>
</head>

<style>
path {
    fill: white;
    stroke: black;
}
</style>

<body>
  <svg width="700" height="220">
     <g transform="translate(200, 110)"></g>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script>
    // Create an arc generator with configuration
    var arcGenerator = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(80)
        .outerRadius(100);

    var arcData = [
        {startAngle: 0, endAngle: Math.PI * 2 / 4, degree: 0},
        {startAngle: Math.PI * 2 / 4, endAngle: Math.PI, degree: 90},
        {startAngle: Math.PI, endAngle: Math.PI * 3 / 2, degree: 180},
        {startAngle: Math.PI * 3 / 2, endAngle: Math.PI * 2, degree: 270},
    ];

    // Create a path element and set its d attribute
    d3.select('g')
        .selectAll('path')
        .data(arcData)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', arcGenerator);

    // Add labels, using .centroid() to position
    d3.select('g')
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(arcData)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .each(function(d) {
            var centroid = arcGenerator.centroid(d);
            d3.select(this)
                .attr('x', centroid[0])
                .attr('y', centroid[1])
                .attr('width', 10)
                .attr('height', 35)
        });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result:[image: image showing rectangles at the centroid position of each arc]

Instead, I would like each rectangle to be placed at the start or end position of each arc and rotated so that each rectangle is portrait oriented (10 px wide and 35 px long).

Here is my: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewilansky/zx7Ltg5c/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create arc data records for the angles you want and use the `centroid()` for these dummy arcs

You have some illegal html after the `g` element.

```js
// Create an arc generator with configuration
    var arcGenerator = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(80)
        .outerRadius(100);
        
    var arcData = [
        {startAngle: 0, endAngle: Math.PI * 2 / 4, degree: 0},
        {startAngle: Math.PI * 2 / 4, endAngle: Math.PI, degree: 90},
        {startAngle: Math.PI, endAngle: Math.PI * 3 / 2, degree: 180},
        {startAngle: Math.PI * 3 / 2, endAngle: Math.PI * 2, degree: 270},
    ];

    var rectData = arcData.map(d => { return {startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle:d.startAngle}; });

    // Create a path element and set its d attribute
    d3.select('g')
        .selectAll('path')
        .data(arcData)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', arcGenerator);

    // Add labels, using .centroid() to position
    d3.select('g')
        .selectAll('.grect')
        .data(rectData)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'grect')
        .attr('transform', d => {
            var centroid = arcGenerator.centroid(d);
            return `translate(${centroid[0]},${centroid[1]})`;
        })
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', -5)
        .attr('y', -17)
        .attr('width', 10)
        .attr('height', 35);
```

```css
path {
 fill: white;
 stroke: black; 
  }
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title>Rotate rectangles to arc positions: 0, 90, 180 and 270 </title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="700" height="220">
    <g transform="translate(200, 110)"></g>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

**Edit**

You can create the `rectData` on the fly.

```
    d3.select('g')
        .selectAll('.grect')
        .data(arcData)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'grect')
        .attr('transform', d => {
            var centroid = arcGenerator.centroid({startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle:d.startAngle});
            return `translate(${centroid[0]},${centroid[1]})`;
        })
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', -5)
        .attr('y', -17)
        .attr('width', 10)
        .attr('height', 35);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the heads-up about the html error. I fixed that.